# Laravel Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, validationrules

I am trying to ignore a unique role for a given ID but I keep getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'user@updated.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: update `users`
>   set `name` = Name, `email` = user@updated.com, `updated_at` =
>   2018-04-06 10:01:27 where `id` = 1)

In my `UserUpdateRequest` class I have the rules set up:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->route()->parameter('user'),
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

`$this->route()->parameter('user')` gets the current model ID.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with my rules here, anyone have any ideas?

Here is where I am making the call to the update:

```
public function update(Requests\UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $result = $this->service->update($request->except(['_token', '_method']));

        if ($result) {
            return back()->with('message', 'Successfully updated');
        }

        return back()->with('message', 'Failed to update');
    }
```

DB:

[image]

Comment: What is the primary key on `users` table?

Comment: @Kyslik The primary key is the id column.

Comment: I think code is correct, you just have two entries in the database and you are trying to change first one with email of the second one. Because of *Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'user@updated.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: **update***

Comment: @Kyslik You were right. I was not passing the ID through so instead it was updating the current logged in user. If you set an answer I will accept.

Comment: Give it to @Matthias S. Good luck! :)

Comment: didn't see you answered that question already here. Sorry I can delete my answer and you can post one if you like :)

Comment: @MatthiasS no big deal, keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was not passing the ID of the user through to the function so it was updating the current logged in user's record instead, as a result it would trigger the unique rule. You can see in the query it was doing `WHERE id =1` because it was updating using `Auth::id();`.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes because you are trying to save a duplicate entry in your database. You can see that in your indexes all e-mails need to be unique.
If you try to change a record to an E-Mail Address that is already used by someone else, you get the integrity constraint error message.

Answer (score -1):

That is a SQL error, you have a unique constraint on sql table. Probably when you made the migration  you added `table->string("email")->unique()`

Comment: That is intended, this should be comment, not an answer.